# Tooltips/Markers not appearing after transition

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a population pyramid with D3.js using with a [template](http://vis.stanford.edu/jheer/d3/pyramid/shift.html) taken from the visualisation group at Stanford. I can't figure out why initially I get tooltips and markers on the graph but once I transition to a different years these are no longer available. Anyone know how I could fix this? Apologies for the length of the code, I'm pretty new to D3/JavaScript so just figured I'd put everything up rather than trying to pinpoint where the error is.

Thanks
    
    
    
    Northern Ireland Teacher Population Pyramid

```
body {
font: 12px sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
color: #888;
}
h1 {
padding-left: 10px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
color: #333;
}
.source {
padding-left: 10px;
}
.source a, .source a:hover {
color: #888;
}
.label {
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 15px;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #dedede;
}
.break {
border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;
margin: 10px 15px 2px 15px;
width: 545px;
}
.years, .controls {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 15;
width: 540;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
}
.years span, .controls span {
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
}
.years .title {
font-size: 13px;
font-variant: small-caps;
letter-spacing: 1;
}
.years a, .controls a {
color: #888;
text-decoration: none;
}
.years a:hover, .controls a:hover {
color: #000;
text-decoration: underline;
}
.years a.y1890 {
color: #bbb;
}
.years a.active {
color: #000;
}
.controls a {
font-variant: small-caps;
letter-spacing: 1;
text-decoration: none;
}
svg {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Northern Ireland Teachers Population Pyramid, 2010-2014</h1>

<div class="source">
    Source: Teachers' Payroll and Pensions Administration System.
</div><script type="text/javascript">

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var y = year;
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: // left arrow
        y = Math.max(2010, year-1);
        break;
    case 39: // right arrow
        y = Math.min(2014, year+1);
        break;
    case 32: // space bar
        toggle();
        return;
}
if (y != year) goto(y);
};

function isYear(d) { return d.year == year; }
function linkClass(y) { return "y"+y.toFixed(0) + (y==year?" active":""); }
function tooltipText(d) {
return d3.format(",")(d.people)
    + " " + (d.sex==1?"men":"women")
    + " aged " + (d.age==60?"60+":d.age+"-"+(d.age+4))
    + " in " + d.year;
}
function barWidth(d) { return x1(d.people); }

function goto(yr, dur) {
dur = dur || 300;
var old = year;
year = yr;

label.text(year);

div.selectAll("span.link a")
   .attr("class", linkClass);

var fb = vis.selectAll("rect.female").data(fdat.filter(isYear), {
    nodeKey: function(node) { return node.getAttribute("id"); },
    dataKey: function(data) { return "f"+(data.year - data.age); }
});
fb.enter("svg:rect")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return "f"+(d.year - d.age); })
    .attr("class", "female")
    .attr("fill", "pink")
    .attr("transform", lTransform)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d.people); })
    .attr("y", yr>old ? 20 : -20)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("opacity", 0.0001)
  .transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("opacity", 1);
fb.exit().transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("y", yr>old ? -20 : 30)
    .attr("opacity", 0.0001)
    .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).remove(); });
fb.transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("transform", lTransform)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d.people); })
    .attr("opacity", 1);
fb.selectAll("title").text(tooltipText);


var mb = vis.selectAll("rect.male").data(mdat.filter(isYear), {
    nodeKey: function(node) { return node.getAttribute("id"); },
    dataKey: function(data) { return "m"+(data.year - data.age); }
});
mb.enter("svg:rect")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return "m"+(d.year - d.age); })
    .attr("class", "male")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("transform", rTransform)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d.people); })
    .attr("y", yr>old ? 20 : -20)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("opacity", 0.0001)
  .transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("opacity", 1);
mb.exit().transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("y", yr>old ? -20 : 30)
    .attr("opacity",0.0001)
    .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).remove(); });
mb.transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .attr("transform", rTransform)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d.people); })
    .attr("opacity", 1);
mb.select("title").text(tooltipText);
}

var timer = undefined;
function stop() {
clearInterval(timer);
timer = undefined;
ctrls.select("a.toggle").text("play");
}
function toggle() {
if (!timer) {
    play();
} else {
    stop();
}
}
function play(rev) {
rev = rev || false;
if (timer) { stop(); }
ctrls.select("a.toggle").text("stop");
var advance = function() {
    var y = year + (rev?-1:1)*1;
    if (y < 2010 || y > 2013) {
        // stop at end points
        stop();
        return;
    } else {
        // else advance
        goto(y, 800);
    }
};
advance();
timer = setInterval(advance, 850);
}

var data = census,
maxp = data.reduce(function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b.people); }, 0),
mdat = data.filter(function(d) { return d.sex==1; })
           .sort(function(a,b) { return b.age - a.age; }),
fdat = data.filter(function(d) { return d.sex==2; })
           .sort(function(a,b) { return b.age - a.age; });

var w = 250,
h = 9 * 40,
bins = d3.range(9),
year = 2010,
y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(bins).rangeBands([0, h], 0.25),
x1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxp]).range([0, w]),
x2 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxp]).range([w, 0]),
rf = "javascript:return false;";

var label = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "label")
.text(year.toFixed(0));

var vis = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", 2*w + 40)
.attr("height", h + 40)
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(20,15)");

// pyramid bar chart

vis.append("svg:g")
.selectAll("text.ages")
.data(bins)
.enter("svg:text")
.filter(function(d) { return d%2==0; })
.attr("class", "ages")
.attr("x", w+15)
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + y.rangeBand() + 7; })
.attr("fill", "#888")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-size", "12px")
.text(function(d) { return (60-d*5).toFixed(0); });

var rTransform = function(d,i) {
return "translate("+(w+30)+","+y(i).toFixed(2)+")";
}
var lTransform = function(d,i) {
return "translate("+x2(d.people).toFixed(2)+","+y(i).toFixed(2)+")";
}
var lEnter = function(d,i) {
return "translate("+w+","+y(i).toFixed(2)+")";
}

var mbars = vis.selectAll("rect.male")
.data(mdat.filter(isYear))
.enter("svg:rect")
.attr("id", function(d) { return "m"+(d.year - d.age); })
.attr("class", "male")
.attr("fill", "steelblue")
.attr("transform", rTransform)
.attr("width", barWidth)
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("opacity", 1);

mbars.append("svg:title").text(tooltipText);

var fbars = vis.selectAll("rect.female")
.data(fdat.filter(isYear))
.enter("svg:rect")
.attr("id", function(d) { return "f"+(d.year - d.age); })
.attr("class", "female")
.attr("fill", "pink")
.attr("opacity", 1)
.attr("transform", lTransform)
.attr("width", barWidth)
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("opacity", 1);

fbars.append("svg:title").text(tooltipText);

// animated intro for bars

mbars.attr("width", 0)
.transition()
  .duration(100)
  .delay(function(d,i) { return 30*i; })
  .attr("width", barWidth);

fbars.attr("width", 0)
.attr("transform", lEnter)
.transition()
  .duration(100)
  .delay(function(d, i) { return 30*i; })
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr("transform", lTransform);

// age label

vis.append("svg:text")
.attr("x", w+15)
.attr("y", h+8)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.attr("fill", "#888")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-size", "13px")
.attr("font-variant", "small-caps")
.attr("letter-spacing", 1)
.text("age");

// gridlines and labels for right pyramid

var rules1 = vis.selectAll("g.rule1")
.data(x1.ticks(5))
.enter("svg:g")
.filter(function(d) { return d > 0; })
.attr("class", "rule1")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+(w+30+x1(d))+",0)";});

rules1.append("svg:line")
.attr("y1", h - 2)
.attr("y2", h + 4)
.attr("stroke", "#bbb");

rules1.append("svg:line")
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("y2", h)
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-opacity", .3);

rules1.append("svg:text")
.attr("y", h + 9)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-size", "12px")
.attr("fill", "#bbb")
.text(function(d) { return (d).toFixed(0); });

// gridlines and labels for left pyramid

var rules2 = vis.selectAll("g.rule2")
.data(x2.ticks(5))
.enter("svg:g")
.filter(function(d) { return d > 0; })
.attr("class", "rule2")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+(x2(d))+",0)";});

rules2.append("svg:line")
.attr("y1", h - 2)
.attr("y2", h + 4)
.attr("stroke", "#bbb");

rules2.append("svg:line")
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("y2", h)
.attr("stroke", "white")
.attr("stroke-opacity", .3);

rules2.append("svg:text")
.attr("y", h + 9)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-size", "12px")
.attr("fill", "#bbb")
.text(function(d) { return (d).toFixed(0); });

d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "break");

var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "years");

div.append("span")
.attr("class", "title")
.text("year");

var ctrls = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "controls");
ctrls.append("span").append("a")
.attr("class", "control back")
.attr("href", "javascript:play(true);")
.text("<< ");
ctrls.append("span").append("a")
.attr("class", "control toggle")
.attr("href", "javascript:toggle();")
.text("play");
ctrls.append("span").append("a")
.attr("class", "control forward")
.attr("href", "javascript:play();")
.text(" >>");

div.selectAll("span.link")
.data(d3.range(2010, 2014, 1))
.enter("span")
.attr("class", "link")
.append("a")
.attr("class", linkClass)
.attr("href", function(d) { return d==1890?null:"javascript:goto("+d+");"; })
.text(function(d) { return d.toFixed(0); });


</script>
```

Comment: Here's your code in a JSFiddle, play with that and get it so it works like yours does, let me know when thats done and ill play around with it see if i can fix your problem :) http://jsfiddle.net/rvocL78t/

Comment: I can't seem to manage to get it working on there properly. I've it up on Codecademy [here](http://www.codecademy.com/figurine89/codebits/OZJTMj/edit) if that's any use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to replace

```
var fb = vis.selectAll("rect.female").data(fdat.filter(isYear), {
    nodeKey: function(node) { return node.getAttribute("id"); },
    dataKey: function(data) { return "f"+(data.year - data.age); }
});
```

with

```
var fb = vis.selectAll("rect.female").data(fdat.filter(isYear));
```

(And the same for variable mb).

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements are rendered in the order that you append them to the DOM. At the beginning, the grid lines are on top of the bars, but after you redraw the bars, they are on top of the grid lines. You need to append the lines after the bars. If you change the lines from white to another color you can see where they are -- that should help with debugging.